# Gridview missing After button clicked

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview

On page Load I will load empty gridview with header. On button clicked I dont want to be gone.

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Portfolio.aspx.cs" Inherits="PortFolio.Portfolio" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Parent" HeaderText="Parent" HeaderStyle-Width="175px" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Child" HeaderText="Child" HeaderStyle-Width="175px" />
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckboxSelectAll" onclick="HeaderCheckBoxClick(this);" runat="server" />
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" onclick="ChildCheckBoxClick(this);" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

code behind

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace PortFolio
{
    public partial class Portfolio : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = new List<string>();
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I'm using `(!IsPostBack)` because I dont want to always load my data on `Page_Load` because my gridview has checkbox that will be missing state if I always load on page load. I'm thinking of using viewstate, but I dont know how.

Weird thing is, if I run this locally the gridview not missing, after publish to https the gridview missing. Please help

Comment: Have you checked browser console for any error?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood there ia no error from console. Just gridview html element missing after click. Is this normal by design. Because after postback my code skip gridview databind

Answer (score 0):

If you have set EnableViewState to "false", then you need to set it to "true" at the page level.